# How to copy over and use a 6GB Microsoft Oulook 2010 .pst file

Tags: microsoft-outlook, ubuntu-10.04, microsoft-office, thunderbird, microsoft-outlook-2010

I had a Win 7 computer that gave a blue screen. I got a replacement.

I used Ubuntu Live cd on the one that crashed to salvage my data. Among many things I have a 6GB MS Outlook 2010 .pst Inbox archive.

I really want to get it back. How do I do it?
Since it is > than 4GB in size I cannot copy it to FAT file systems.

Questions:

1. How do I copy it to my new Win 7 laptop? I am hoping it use it with Outlook 2010 on my new computer.
2. If I cannot use it on my new laptop, can I atleast use it on Ubuntu? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, I would try to fix the bluescreen error. That being said, if you really can't for one reason or another, I would do one of the following:

From Ubuntu, try using a zip program or similar to "split" the file in to multiple sections, and then reassemble on the new machine - many zip programs allow you to configure how big you want the chunks. I can not be more specific as I do not know linux programs that can do this...

(I think 7-zip is only Windows, but I just read a link about a Linux port in the Ubuntu repository. You can try that, or possibly running in Wine - otherwise, try to find a linux program that does the same).

I think splitting is the best solution in your case. Other than this, Samba can be a bit of a pain to get working, so, I would recommend trying to install  [Filezilla server](http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server)  on your laptop, then downloading filezilla to the Ubuntu live and simply copying it that way (If you need any detailed instructions/guides, let me know).

Finally, the quickest solution, but possibly not recommended is if your old machine was a desktop, you can take out your laptops hard drive and copy it directly to there and then put it back in (as long as you are not using Bitlocker/similar).

Or... on the last solution, if you have a USB caddy of some sort, you can take out your old hard drive and connect it directly to your new machine.

Comment: I ran into another problem. I tried to install Ubuntu 10.04 on the hard disk drive (/dev/sda2). This partition had my data too. I killed the updates after the install and then the computer wouldn't boot. Now when I try to use the live CD and mount the parttion, it won't mount. I remember during install the OS files were being kept at /dev/sda2. Should I still hope that I would be able to salvage my data?

Comment: without knowing how far you got, or exactly what you did, I can't easily help you. If you performed a format and install, it is unlikely you will be able to recover many larger files, but there is a chance you can recover a few smaller files using recovery tools (can't list any for Linux, but, there are a number of questions here that can help you). If you installed on the same drive without formatting, it is possible you can do a windows startup repair to rebuild the loader. But, without knowing exactly what happened, I can't really help you much further. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

> Since it is > than 4GB in size I cannot copy it to FAT file systems.

NTFS works okay on pendrives (although slightly slow).

Alternatively you can split it to several pieces; for example:

```
rar -v4294967290b a mail.rar mail.pst
```

Later simply extract the file with WinRAR or `unrar`.

On Ubuntu, the Evolution mail client should be able to *import* data from PST files, but not use them directly.